# Smarty 3 output the current position inside foreach loop.

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

Instead of:

```
{foreach $rows as $row}
    <li class="item{if $row@first} item-first{elseif $row@last} item-last{/if}">{$row.title}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
{foreach $rows as $row}
    <li class="item item-{$row@position}">{$row.title}</li>
{/foreach}
```

This could output:

> item-first 
>   item-last

I guess if there is only 1 row then it would need to output both of the above?

Comment: Ideally I was looking for a way to do this in smarty? Maybe as a custom modifier or plugin. The idea is to make the template a little cleaner for repetitive task as first/last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to describe condition outside the loop and use [@iteration](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration) property. For example:

Inside your PHP file:

```
$lastIteration = count($rows);
$smarty->assign('classMapping', array(
    1 => 'item-first', // iteration always starts at one
    $lastIteration => 'item-last',
));
```

Inside your template:

```
{foreach $rows as $row}
    <li class="item {$classMapping[$row@iteration]}">{$row.title}</li>
{/foreach}
```

But I think that your code (with `if` statement) is not so bad.

---

**Update**

This is a source code of the Smarty 3 `foreach` function: http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_foreach.php

Look at the class `Smarty_Internal_Compile_Foreach` and at the method `complile()` (here is a "shortened" version of this method, which describes how it uses `@first` modifier):

```
public function compile($args, $compiler, $parameter)
{                
    $ItemVarName = '$' . trim($item, '\'"') . '@';

    // evaluates which Smarty variables and properties have to be computed
    if ($has_name) {
        $usesSmartyFirst = strpos($tpl->source->content, $SmartyVarName . 'first') !== false;                        
    } else {
        $usesSmartyFirst = false;            
    }        

    $usesPropFirst = $usesSmartyFirst || strpos($tpl->source->content, $ItemVarName . 'first') !== false;

    return $output; // output - is a result of the compilation process
}
```

So you can create your own internal `foreach` modifier (`@position`, for example) only after changing Smarty core classes.

Comment: This would mean over 100 different changes. Ideally I was looking for a way to do this in smarty? Maybe as a custom modifier or plugin. The idea is to make the template a little cleaner for repetitive task as first/last